# Internal server errors after successful ckan install

Tags: apache, ubuntu-14.04, ckan

I installed ckan from source on ubuntu 14.04 as described [here](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/install-from-source.html#source-install-troubleshooting), set up [datastore extension](http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/datastore.html) until the part where I had to present an api-key. So I went to testing my ckan installation and getting an api-key.

After creating a user I ran into

> Server error. An internal server error occurred.

when going to my profile or regenerating an api key. Additionally, I do not see the buttons "Add Dataset", "Add Organization" or "Add Group".

I suspect is has something to do with some authorization settings, so I wanted to look up a log file.

But in my folder /var/log/apache2 I cannot find a ckan log as I should according to http://docs.ckan.org/en/latest/maintaining/installing/deployment.html#log-files.

Any ideas, what the problem is or how to track it down?

Comment: Do you see anything special in the apache error log? ISE can be anything from file system permission or ownership issues to malformed .htaccess files.

Comment: No, I really can't find anything that would be related in the apache error log.

Comment: The log files are set by the `ErrorLog` and `CustomLog` options in your apache config, which by default is at: `/etc/apache2/sites-available/ckan_default`. Check also you have the logging set-up in `/etc/ckan/default/apache.wsgi` and `production.ini` has the `## Logging configuration` section unchanged from what's in `deployment.ini_tmpl`. This ensures everything is as it should be from following the deployment instructions you mention.